# Redefining enumerate counters in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, lists, enumerate

I'd like to do two things with the `enumerate` environment in `beamer`.

1. I'd like to reformat it so that it shows up as

   ```
   (1) An item
     a. A subitem
     b. Another subitem
   ```
2. I'd like to be able to refer to these items with the usual `\ref` tags. Unfortunately, the only way I've found of getting the display of items inside of the environment right doesn't deliver the correct result for the references.

Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\insertenumlabel)}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\alph{enumii}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo\label{item:1}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Bar\label{item:2}
  \item Zip\label{item:3}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Reference to ``Foo'': (\ref{item:1}).

Reference to ``bar'': (\ref{item:2}). 

Reference to ``zip'': (\ref{item:3}).
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, that results in all three references in arabic numbers, i.e., `(1)`, `(1)`, and `(2)` for the three `\ref`'s, in that order.

The desired output is for `(\ref{item:3})` to be rendered as `(1b)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

redefine the begin of an enumerate

```
\documentclass{beamer}   
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}
  {\renewcommand\theenumii{\theenumi\alph{enumii}}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\insertenumlabel)}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\alph{enumii}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo\label{item:1}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Bar\label{item:2}
  \item Zip\label{item:3}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Reference to ``Foo'': (\ref{item:1}).

Reference to ``bar'': (\ref{item:2}). 

Reference to ``zip'': (\ref{item:3}).
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a partial solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\insertenumlabel)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo\label{item:1}
  \begin{enumerate}[a.]
  \item Bar\label{item:2}
  \item Zip\label{item:3}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

Reference to ``Foo'': \ref{item:1}

Reference to ``bar'': \ref{item:2} 

Reference to ``zip'': \ref{item:3}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This fixes the labels in the nested environment to be `a.` and `b.`.  But the `\ref`s end up the same.

With the same code in an `article` class with the `enumerate` package, you would see your second effect, too: the labels for bar and zip are set as `1a` and `1b`.  But to get beamer to do the same thing requires a bit of digging.  I'll try to do that digging and see what I can find.

Comment: The source file to dig in is `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`.  Can't find where the label is set and why it behaves differently from `enumerate.sty` (since that package is included in beamer).